# Active Admin: Including Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, activeadmin

I want to add Gon ( https://github.com/gazay/gon ) to my activeadmin

but I need to add the line

```
<%= include_gon %>
```

to the head section in the layout

but I can't figure out how?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To add to Mexxer's comment. Go to `config/initializers/active_admin.rb

At the bottom of the page, you'll find the following:

```
# == Register Stylesheets & Javascripts
#
# We recommend using the built in Active Admin layout and loading
# up your own stylesheets / javascripts to customize the look
# and feel.
#
# To load a stylesheet:
#   config.register_stylesheet 'my_stylesheet.css'
#
# To load a javascript file:
#   config.register_javascript 'my_javascript.js'
```

Uncomment the last line and replace my_javascript.js with your file, like this...

```
# To load a javascript file:
config.register_javascript 'invoices.js'
```

That file can be located at `app/assets/javascripts/invoices.js`

Comment: `register_javascript` option has been deprecated in favor of requiring the JS file in `active_admin.js`

Answer (score 6):

This may also be relevant:

```
# The Active Admin equivalent of putting this in your application layout:
# <head>
#   <%= cloudinary_js_config %>
# </head>

module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    module Pages
      class Base < Arbre::HTML::Document

        alias_method :original_build_head, :build_active_admin_head

        def build_active_admin_head
          original_build_head

          within @head do
            text_node include_gon
          end
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/seanlinsley/9786622

Answer (score 5):

The register_javascript config will be deprecated in V2.

So instead of change `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`, you can change `assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`, just put the name file of your .js like

```
//= require active_admin/base
//= require activeadmin_addons/all
//= require masks
```

this file is located inside of assets folder, as masks.js

Answer (score 0):

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  javascripts = [] 
  javascripts << "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key="
  javascripts += ActiveAdmin.application.javascripts.to_a
  ActiveAdmin.application.javascripts.replace javascripts
end
```

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/340#issuecomment-92512556

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is

```
active_admin_namespace.head
```

Very convenient. Do not forget to **html_safe** concatenated string.