# Can ActiveAdmin serve individual javascript files in development via Rails asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

I've configured ActiveAdmin to include my own javascript, following these instructions [Active Admin: Including Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918213/active-admin-including-javascript).
In my `initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
  config.register_javascript 'application.js.coffee'
```

But now I get one massive precompiled `application.js` served to me (application.js.coffee `require`s many small files); in development mode when I visit the active admin pages. I still want the individual javascript files to served individually for easier debugging. Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `development.rb`:

```
config.assets.debug = false
```