# How to include gazon/gon in ActiveAdmin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Im working on a Rails Project with ActiveAdmin and I want to use 'gem gon' to handle the sending of data in my javascripts file. 
The problem I encountered is that gon variable is not recognized in dashboard.rb of activeadmin.

> undefined local variable or method `gon'

Here is my code so far as this railscast guide [instructs](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast):

```
# creat gon variable
gon.test = "hey there"
render partial: 'graph/dashboard_graph.html.erb' #this is a partial
```

I found this post but I have a different scenario.
 https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2450

I also found this one with the same scenario but no clear solution:
 [Active Admin: Including Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918213/active-admin-including-javascript)

I have been trapped in this error for the whole day and been spending my time searching on how to properly include gon in ActiveAdmin but I could not find solution.Im hoping that you could give inputs.

Thank You.

Chkm8

Answer (score 3):

In /config/initializers/ create new file for example: activeadmin.rb and paste this:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    module Pages
      class Base < Arbre::HTML::Document

        alias_method :original_build_head, :build_active_admin_head

        def build_active_admin_head
          original_build_head

          within @head do
            text_node Gon::Base.render_data({ })
          end
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

I had the same problem and this worked for me.
If you're not using Rails 4 instead of *Gon::Base.render_data({ })* it may be *include_gon*

Comment: Working in ActiveAdmin 2.3.1. Did you restart rails, @bxorcloud?

Answer (score 3):

The latest stable version of active_admin uses **head** instead of **@head**,

when getting the below error in latest version using @head

> ArgumentError - Can't be in the context of nil.

use the below code to fix it.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    module Pages
      class Base < Arbre::HTML::Document
        alias original_build_head build_active_admin_head

        def build_active_admin_head
          original_build_head

          within head do
            text_node Gon::Base.render_data({})
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```